# Bootstrap Drop down JavaScript not working for multiple drop downs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using JavaScript to change Twitter Bootstrap drop down menu to select. The problem I am facing is that the script is working for all of the fields. How can I modify it to be working separately for each drop down?

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {
    $(".btn-default-dropdown").html('<span class="pull-left">'+$(this).text()+'</span><span class="lx-icon icon-dropdown-arrow media-middle pull-right"></span>');
});
```

Comment: not sure if i understand your question, are there multiple dropdowns all being effected by a click event?

Comment: Yes, once I select on of the drop downs it changes all of them. because all of them have the same class: btn-default-dropdown . So i would like to modify the script to be working individually.

Comment: can you give us a fiddle ? (If steviekins have not answer  yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your click event function is going to end up effecting other dropdowns than the one you clicked, because the selector `$(".btn-default-dropdown")` is going to select any dropdown in the page. You need to narrow down the results of the selector by finding the dropdown related to the clicked anchor tag like so:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {    
    $(this).parent(".btn-group")...//find the element inside this group
}
```

Comment: with this solution nothing is being selected. the drop down is not selecting.

Comment: do I have to place btn-group somewhere outside of the script in the html code ? to initialize the group ?

Comment: @JohnSiniger can you put your HTML in your question? then we can rewrite the answer to correctly select what you are looking for